# Jquery search box implementation

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to implement a search box on web page using Jquery. But the search is not working as expected. when user enter something in the search box. It should search for item name like Radio Subscriber,Access Control List etc.

Also can anyone help me in implementing similar search on entire web page. Any help would appreciated. Thank you

**Html:**

```
<div id="form_search">
<form class="searchFaq" action="#">
<input class="filterinput1" placeholder="Search for Catalog Items" type="text">
</form>
</div>

<div id="allItems" class="col-sm-3">
<a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;" href="catalog.do?sysparm_id=36c0754109715940963780fde6ca6e78&sysparm_table=sc_cat_item">
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 275px; width: 275px; display: block;">
<div class="panel-heading" style="height: 90px; display: block;">
<div class="span_item" style="color: rgb(66, 139, 202); display: block;">Radio Subscriber</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body" style="display: block;">
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div id="allItems" class="col-sm-3">
<a style="text-decoration: none" href="catalog.do?sysparm_id=193ca5f809791940963780fde6ca6e6e&sysparm_table=sc_cat_item">
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height:275px;width:275px">
<div class="panel-heading" style="height:90px">
<div class="span_item" style="color:#428bca">Access Control List</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
  jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
      return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
  };

  //live search function
  function live_search(list) {
    $(".filterinput1")
      .change( function () {
        //getting search value
        var searchtext = $(this).val();
        if(searchtext) {
          //finding If content matches with searck keyword
          $matches = $(list).find('div:Contains(' + searchtext + ')').parent();
          //hiding non matching lists
          $('div', list).not($matches).slideUp();
          //showing matching lists
          $matches.slideDown();

        } else {
          //if search keyword is empty then display all the lists
          $(list).find("div").slideDown(200);
        }
        return false;
      })
    .keyup( function () {
        $(this).change();
    });
  }

  $(function () {
    live_search($("#allItems"));
  });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you, but I have developed a jQuery plugin that perfoms search operation accross loaded data.

The developer provides a datasource (Array of objects with predifined properties) that get organized in a tree structure (parent-children related). The plugin provides the ability to seacrh over the loaded data and select some or all of them.

For detailed information checkout the [README](https://github.com/kapantzak/SearchAreaControl) file.

There is also a [DEMO](https://kapantzak.github.io/SearchAreaControl/) page here where you can view the plugin's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your case insensitive search itself works perfectly. The problem appears when you apply it to your list of search candidates. You select only the first parent level as divs to remain visible. This way their parents and the initially selected div are being made invisible. This is obviously not what you want.

When you change the line

```
$matches = $(list).find('div:Contains(' + searchtext + ')').parent();
```

to

```
$matches = $(list).find('div:Contains(' + searchtext + ')').parents().addBack();
```

Your search box should work as intended. `parents()` will select parents of all "generations" (levels) and `addBack()` will add the actual div itself back to the selection so the whole chain will be in your jquery collection `$matches` .